# How can I send the devextreme chart svg(image file) to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using `Devxtreme` charts JS for my analytics application.
Each chart is created with the `svg` image file.
Now my requirement is to send each one(one image at a time) of the image file to the controller on some client action(`Add to PPT` button click action).
i.e.

[image]

Should the `image` first be converted into `bytes` and then pass it to the `controller` using `ajax` call with the image bytes in as `data` property?
or

is there a possible way to acheive this?